¿Como validar si un procedimiento (alarma) ya esta corriendo?
Tengo el siguiente código,el cual corresponde a una alarma, el código lo tengo en un archivo BroadcastReceiver, código que se activa al encender el teléfono, el mismo código lo tengo en el archivo MainActivity.class. En ambos casos funciona bien
El problema que tengo es que cuando abro el MainActivity, he notado que en unos casos la alarma se reinicia y se pierde la secuencia que traía desde el encendido y en otros casos he notado que corren dos alarmas.
¿Como puedo validar en el Mainactivity si la alarma ya esta corriendo?
Gracias
private void startServiceByAlarm(Context context) {

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, Alarmas.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long intervalTime = 3600*1000;
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, startTime, intervalTime, pendingIntent);

    }


En realidad no se valida, lo que debes realizar es usar el flag FLAG_NO_CREATE del PendingIntent, esta bandera evitaría crear un nuevo PendingIntent.

FLAG_NO_CREATE Bandera que indica que si el PendingIntent
descrito aún no existe, simplemente devuelve nulo en lugar de crearlo.

Usa el flag FLAG_NO_CREATE en lugar de FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT:
private void startServiceByAlarm(Context context) {

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, Alarmas.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE | PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long intervalTime = 3600*1000;
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, startTime, intervalTime, pendingIntent);

    }


Hola Jorgesys, voy a hacer unas pruebas con lo que sugieres y te cuento, gracias

Claro que si @Linamar

Ya lo pude implementar y me quedo como quería gracias Jorgesys
